# Is it possible to do pay-pal chain payments using credit card?

Tags: paypal, xcode6, paypal-sandbox, ios8.1

Hello everyone in my application i'm using pay-pal API with selecting mode as chain payment. My question is shall i use credit card for pay-pal chain payment?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "guest checkout" option enabled in the checkout flow for Adaptive Payments, so people can use a credit card without an account.  There isn't any way to collect the card data yourself, though, and process it as a chained payment directly with an API.

Technically, you could get it done with Payments Pro to process the credit card, and then setup an automated solution of some sort (with IPN or CRON job on server, for example) to forward funds to 3rd party PayPal accounts.